# Problem with integrating to find volume

Tags: graphing-functions, maple, implicit-function-theorem

I want to calculate the volume of the hyperboloid between the two planes:

$hyp:{x}^{2}+1/4\,{y}^{2}-{z}^{2}=5$

$plane1:=z+x/2+3=0$

$plane2:=z+x/2-3=0$

Because of symmetry, I confine my bounds to the positive z-axis, and positive y-axis. Now, I'd like to get the intersection between the green plane(plane2) and the hyperboloid, for y-values > 0.
Initially i would have solved plane2 and hyp for z, let's say zPlane2 and zHyp, and solve(zHyp=zPlane2), but this doesn't work either. 
I guess because the information of the y-variable gets lost when solving plane2 for z... Can someone push me in the right direction?

Thanks.

[image]

[image: Hyperboloid, with 2 planes]
[image: Upperview]

Answer (score 0):

Okay, i got it.

```
hyp:=x^2+(y/2)^2-z^2=5:
vlak1:=z+1/2*x+3=0:
vlak2:=z+1/2*x-3=0:
```

## I defined them explicit this way:

```
f(x,y):=solve(vlak1,z);
g(x,y):=solve(vlak2,z);
h(x,y):=solve(hyp,z)[1];
```

So now it was possible to solve them, to obtain the intersection

```
solve(g(x,y)=h(x,y),y);
```